# The norm squared of a moment map

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, morse-theory, symplectic-topology

I am studying the paper by E. Lerman:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410568

Let $(M,\sigma)$ be a connected symplectic manifold with a Hamiltonian action of a compact Lie group $G$, so that there exist a moemnt map
 $$\mu : M\to\mathcal{G}^\ast$$
$\mathcal{G}^\ast$ being the dual of the Lie algebra of $G$. We assume that $\mu$ is $G$-equivariant:
$$\mu(g\cdot x)=\mathrm{Ad}_g^\ast\circ\mu(x)$$
and that $\mu$ is proper (the preimage of any compact is compact).
Let $f=\|\mu\|^2$ (for an $\mathrm{Ad}$-invariant norm on $\mathcal{G}^\ast$).

I know that the moment map is important by:

1. a convexity theorem of Atiyah and Guillemin-Sternberg.
2. symplectic reduction, where the quotient of the zero level of the moment map by the group makes it possible to construct new symplectic manifolds.

Hence my question:

> What is the motivation to study the norm squared of a moment map? in particular, why is it important to know that the zero level set of the moment map is a retract by deformation of a piece of the manifold?

As I understand it, $f$ behaves like a Morse-Bott function (Kirwan works) and that the stable manifold of a critical component of $f$ is a submanifold.
That the gradient flow of $f$ is defined for all $t\geq0$. Here Lerman asserts that this is true because $f$ is proper, but $x^3$ is proper but its gradient $-3x^2\partial_x$ is not defined for all $t\geq0$.

I think we have to show that $\nabla_f$ is $G$-invariant and therefore complete.

That $f$ is real analytic to show that the limit of a trajectory of any point $\phi_t(x)$ is reduced to a point $\phi_\infty(x)$. That the applications $t\to\phi_t(x)$ and $x\to\phi_\infty(x)$ are continuous.

Comment: I don’t understand your comment about the gradient - for what t is the gradient undefined?